# Manage multiple flavours to my project on GitHub repo

Tags: git, github

Assume that I created a project "hustle" on GitHub. I have 2 different parts of it, one for **desktop**, one for **mobile**. How can I manage both the flavours simultaneously on **Github** without creating different repositories?

Comment: Branches? Or better yet, write your code in such a way that the code is desktop/mobile-aware without you having to maintain separate code bases.  Reading about responsive web development might be a good start for you.

Comment: It largely depends on what you mean/expect by "managing" and "simultaneously". You can add as many projects (from any editor) to a single repository — one by one, per commit, or all at once.

Comment: Monorepo is probably the term you’re looking for. It’s a method to handle multiple projects, which usually share dependencies, in one repo.

Comment: @PDK "Manage simultaneously" means I want to release updates for both the parts time to time.

Comment: @Marc Thanks for your reply. My application is installable so it is different for both Desktop and mobile. Branches are good but it always says- you are x commits behind master branch. I want a branch that is completely isolated from changes in other branches